# Multiple strings in LabelField or RichTextField in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to add multiple strings in the LabelField or RichTextField in my application. So that i'm able to control the font size of both the strings and also i'm able to click on this row to navigate.

eg.

#### Title

date

Comment: u can set the font of text for any labelfield or rich textfield.dont understand what do u mean by multiple strings.do u wish to show them in next lines..Which row u want to click????   may b i dont understand ur question.Plz elaborate...

Comment: @Swati : By multiple strings i mean that, i have 2 strings namely title and date and i want to display "Date" string below the "Title" String. The font size of the Date string needs to be kept smaller than the Title field

Comment: I believe u r creating a list field and want to display content in the row.If YES i would suggest you to create 2 labels and set their position inside the layout manager in the listfield.If NO then u can go ahead for Farid's answer

Comment: @swati : I'm not using list field. I'm using rich text field and displaying the two strings as (title) +"\n"+(date) to put a line break within the RichTextField and also able to set the font, but i want to set different fonts for both strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RichTextField to have multiple strings with multiple fonts. Check the RichTextField class in the APIs

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/RichTextField.html